# Is there a workaround for Debian file-completion trashing $_?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have years of experience on Slackware linux, and have never seen this problem there. Lately I have been administering Debian servers, and this has become an annoyance.

I frequently use "$_" in a bash command to repeat the final argument of the previously-typed command. Sometimes, I get the following behavior:

```
dschrag@mo:~/dev/dancer$ ls -l app/db/schema/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 dschrag dschrag 268 May 19 10:51 gau_account.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 dschrag dschrag 558 May 19 13:02 gau_import.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 dschrag dschrag 270 May 19 13:09 gau_source.sql
dschrag@mo:~/dev/dancer$ cd $_
-bash: cd: _filedir: No such file or directory
dschrag@mo:~/dev/dancer$
```

I've looked around enough to see that `_filedir` is used in many pre-defined (by default) shell functions defined in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

I use file-completion without thinking, to the point it's hard for me to figure out the exact thing I am doing when this glitch occurs. Has anyone taken the trouble to dig deeper into this?

Comment: Does/did that also happen when using the keyboard shortcut `ALT-.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple tracing**

First, you can figure out that what actually happen when you using bash completion with `cd` command:

```
$ complete -p | grep cd
complete -F _filedir_xspec cdiff
complete -o nospace -F _cdrecord wodim
complete -o nospace -F _cdrecord cdrecord
complete -o nospace -F _cd cd
```

You can see a function `_cd` will be called when you use completion with `cd`. So you know that some thing happened inside `_cd` function causes your `$_` variable value had been altered.

Looking into `_cd` function: (In my Ubuntu 12.04.4, it's in `/etc/bash_completion`)

```
# This meta-cd function observes the CDPATH variable, so that cd additionally
# completes on directories under those specified in CDPATH.
#
_cd()
{
    local cur IFS=$'\n' i j k
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur

    # try to allow variable completion
    if [[ "$cur" == ?(\\)\$* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -v -P '$' -- "${cur#?(\\)$}" ) )
        return 0
    fi
    ....
        _filedir -d

    if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        i=${COMPREPLY[0]}
        if [[ "$i" == "$cur" && $i != "*/" ]]; then
            COMPREPLY[0]="${i}/"
        fi
    fi

    return 0
}
```

It does many things, causes your old `$_` lost. Maybe you have trouble with line `_filedir -d`. (In my test, I got `$_` changed to `-d`)

To preventing your wanted `$_` from losing, you can save its value immediately when you enter `_cd` function, then restore this value to `$_` before leaving `_cd`:

```
_cd()
{
    local __=$_

    ....

    : $__
    return 0
}
```

The trick here is `:`, it means do nothing in `bash`, and it has one parameter `$__` (which is your wanted `$_` value), causing `$_` is set to old value before you enter `_cd` function.

**Conclusion**

It's very difficult to make `bash completion` does not trashing `$_` variable. With above example, you only prevented it from trashing with `cd`. With others function in `bash_completion` and all files under `/etc/bash_completion.d/`, you have to do the same thing. This is not a robust solution.

If you want to get the last parameter of the last command line, try using `bash history expansion` instead:

```
$ echo 1 2 3
1 2 3
$ echo !$
echo 3
3
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got programmable completion ("bash completion") enabled. That's done by sourcing `/etc/bash_completion` or `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` somewhere in your bashrc. For example, in the skeleton bashrc on jessie:

```bash
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

One of the completions is overwriting `$_`. The quick workaround would be to not load bash-completion.

Another workaround is to do your filename completions with the `complete-filename` function instead of the `complete` function. That'd mean pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (depending on your terminal setup) instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>. You can change which keys those are bound to with `bind` or by editing `~/.inputrc`.

And, I suppose, file a bug report against bash-completion.