# $_ not working with copy and move commands

Tags: bash, cp, gnome-terminal, mv, mkdir

I face the problem with
 `$_` usage, 
which `$_` special parameter in terminal, And its call the last argument of the previous command.

It was not work with `cp` and `mv` command in gnome-terminal.It happen to me during folder creation and `mv` or `cp` file with $_ like below

```
 mkdir test
 cp file.c $_
```

instead of copying file to destination , it create a file in current directory named `_filedir`.

Same happen with `mv` command

```
mkdir test
mv file.c $_
```

instead of moving file to destination, It moving in the name `_filedir`.

To find the problem i use echo

```
$ mkdir test
$ echo $_
_filedir
```

Why is $_ not working with cp, mv commands?

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there a workaround for Debian file-completion trashing $_?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131003)

Comment: @MichaelHomer I can able to `cd` directory or even get echo after `ls `command after using `ls` , I got the directory name.But with this above scenario, Its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_ - Gives the last argument to the previous command. At the shell startup, it gives the absolute filename of the shell script being executed. When you execute

```
mkdir test
mv file.c $_
```

Check if your mv, cp is an alias

In bash to acces the last arg to the previous command in History use !:$ ,like:

```
> mkdir test
> mv file.c !:$
mv file.c test
```

Comment: `mv, cp` not alias in my bash.  I execute it as normal terminal command not a script.  By your instrunction mv work with `!:$` but not `cp`. Thank your for this help.

Comment: what's the error that's returned? remember that !:$ will just take the value of the previous command in history last arg; so you can assign it; ex: mkdir test [ENTER] last_param="!:$", so now the variable $last_param will retain the name 'test' even if you execute intermediary commands

Comment: also if you use $_ in a script, so u don't get  'interference' form bash_completion or others, you shouldn't encounter any more troubles like described in your first post

Comment: it not work with `cp` command, it create the file inthe name  of **_filedir**, similar to making copying a file